# Obtaining drive/storage health via HP iLo 4 CLI

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo

On our HP Proliant servers, I can obtain the drive or storage health from the iLo CLI:

```
</>hpiLO-> show system1/drives1/

status=0
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED
Sun Sep 23 16:29:00 2018

/system1/drives1
  Targets
  Properties
    Group=1, Firmware Version=1.14
    Bay 1 - drive status=Ok; UID=Off
    Bay 2 - drive status=Ok; UID=Off
    Bay 3 - drive status=Ok; UID=Off
    Bay 4 - drive status=Ok; UID=Off
```

This works great on our iLo 2 and 3 boxes, but iLo 4 doesn't have the "drives" target:

```
</>hpiLO-> show system1/drives1

status=2
status_tag=COMMAND PROCESSING FAILED
error_tag=INVALID OPTION
Sun Sep 23 16:26:22 2018
```

The Agentless Management Service (AMS) and Health drivers are installed and running:
[image]

and I can see the storage health from the iLo web interface. iLo firmware is on the latest version.

Is there any way to obtain the storage health and information from the iLo 4 CLI, in the same way I can for iLo 2 and 3 servers?

Comment: According to official docs you did everything right to display health status, maybe you should ask HP support. Maybe they just disabled this feature in the CLI and rely only on their Web Interface for "advanced" information or removed it from the CLI because you can just read drive health values from withing the operating system. Would be a bummer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can do it via so called SMASH CLP (ILO4 CLI) as there is no /system1/drives* target, but you can do it via RIBCL XML.
You can download archive with samples of RIBCL scripts from [here](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_76bfa460792d4f7cbc0aac234e)
You will need to use locfg.pl perl script against Get_Embedded_Health.xml file.
Then execute it against ILO IP address

```
./locfg.pl -s 192.168.10.10 -f Get_Embedded_Health.xml -u YourILOUser -p YourILOPassword
```

Output will be in xml format and will have quite a lot of data, since default xml will request not only storage status, but other things as well.
If you want to limit it only to storage status - you can make xml payload look like below

```
<RIBCL VERSION="2.22">
  <LOGIN USER_LOGIN="adminname" PASSWORD="password">
    <SERVER_INFO MODE="read">
      <GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH>
        <GET_ALL_STORAGE/>        
          <!--            iLO 4 only - 1.30 or later.                -->
      </GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH>
    </SERVER_INFO>
  </LOGIN>
 </RIBCL>
```

When I test it with HP DL380 Gen9 with ILO4 - I get quite comprehensive list of my physical drives, logical drives, serial numbers, capacities etc. Basically all I can see in ILO 4 Web Interface System Information -> Storage is reported in xml output.